# Algolia Multilingual Search

Tags: multilingual, algolia

In Algolia's documentation the below is stated:
"Our engine is language-agnostic: both alphabet-base and symbol-based languages such as Chinese, Japanese or Korean are supported."

- How do you determine the language analyser? for example how do you determines the difference between es_ES and es_MX
- Which is the better approach for better search result single index vs index per language

Answer (score 0):

In our specific case we add attributes like:

- title_en
- title_de
- ....

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how the language analyser is chosen?